# mysqld_exporter refusing to connect to mariadb

Tags: mysql, mariadb, prometheus, exporter

I am running MariaDB and myqld_exporter both from docker. I run them like so :

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:3306:3306 --name mariadbtest -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypass -d mariadb
docker run -p 9104:9104 -e DATA_SOURCE_NAME="root:mypass@(127.0.0.1:3306)/" prom/mysqld-exporter
```

Replacing the `127.0.0.1` IP with `localhost` or my docker-machine ip default of `192.168.99.100` makes no difference either, as I always get the following output after executing the second command :

```
$ docker run -p 9104:9104 -e DATA_SOURCE_NAME="root:mypass@(127.0.0.1:3306)/" prom/mysqld-exporter
    time="2017-10-17T12:26:57Z" level=info msg="Starting mysqld_exporter (version=0.10.0, branch=master, revision=80680068f15474f87847c8ee8f18a2939a26196a)" so
    urce="mysqld_exporter.go:460"
    time="2017-10-17T12:26:57Z" level=info msg="Build context (go=go1.8.1, user=root@3b0154cd9e8e, date=20170425-11:24:12)" source="mysqld_exporter.go:461"
    time="2017-10-17T12:26:57Z" level=error msg="Error pinging mysqld: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: getsockopt: connection refused" source="mysqld_exporter.go:268"

    time="2017-10-17T12:26:57Z" level=info msg="Listening on :9104" source="mysqld_exporter.go:479"
```

My intention is to have Prometheus use the exporter metrics to monitor MariaDB

Answer (score 1):

it's a bit nicer to use `links` instead of ip adresses. You can start the exporter with `docker run -p 9104:9104 --link mariadbtest -e DATA_SOURCE_NAME="root:mypass@(mariadbtest:3306)/" prom/mysqld-exporter`. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/#connect-with-the-linking-system

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, it is certainly an improvement!

Answer (score 0):

Should anyone find it useful, I figured out the commands that do work :

```
docker run -p 3306:3306 --name mariadbtest -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypass -d mariadb
docker run -p 9104:9104 -e DATA_SOURCE_NAME="root:mypass@(192.168.99.100:3306)/" prom/mysqld-exporter
```

Comment: Looks like you just changed the IP from `127.0.0.1` to `192.168.99.100`?